# Using a text file to receive a string for a variable in Python, without defining it

Tags: python, variables, text

I have a text file in which there are several variables. Most of them are used in a Bash script of mine, but I'd like to use the same text file for my Python script. For the lines that are not properly formatted for Python, I want my script to just ignore. For those that are properly formatted, I want the script to check and if it's the variable I'm looking for - use it.

import sys
import re

```
for ln in open("thefile.txt"):
        m = re.match(r"(?P<varname>[^=]*)\s*=\s*(?P<value>.+)", ln)
        if m:
                varname = m.group("varname")
                value_string = m.group("value")
                value = eval(value_string)
                print value
                # so if the variables name is THISVARIABLE, get that value:
                if varname == "THISVARIABLE":
                        mypythonvariable == value
```

I'm getting the following error:

**NameError: name 'Somevariableinmytextfile' is not defined**

The Somevariableinmytextfile is the first variable in that file.

My question:

Do I have to define every variable in the txt file, in order to get rid of this error? If not, what shall I do? I'm very new at Python. This is my first program.

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting? I doubt it literally says `'Somevariableinmytextfile'`.

Comment: I think it is because you use `eval`.

Comment: could you show us few example lines from thefile.txt?

Comment: The "somevarianble..."  is the first variable in my list. At the moment "infothing".

Comment: A few examples from thefile.txt (one on each row, although I can't make a line break here):    infothing=/home/box/                   infonumber=125

Answer (score 1):

The error is `eval` complaining that the contents of `value_string` have no meaning as a whatever-it-is.

The *real* error is using `eval` at all. (A good post on the pitfalls can be found [here](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/).) **You don't even need to `eval` here** - leaving `value_string` as the string the regex gave you will be *just fine*.

## The problem with the present approach

Sample `thefile.txt`:

```
foo=bar
baz=42
quux=import os; os.shutdown()
```

- When parsing `foo`, Python complains that `bar` isn't defined. (Simple.)
- When parsing `bar`, Python gives you an `int` instead of a `str`. (No real problem...)
- When parsing `quux`, Python shuts down your computer. (*Uh oh!*)

## Why you don't need `eval`

You want a string value, correct? The regex already gives you a string!

```
varname = m.group("varname")
value = m.group("value")
print value
if varname == "THISVARIABLE":
    mypythonvariable = value # You meant = instead of ==?
```

Comment: I did mean = (assign) rather than == (compare). Yes. And thank you very much for a great answer!

Comment: @PaoloVacirca The code, with my fixes, works fine for me on Python 2.7.3 (WinRT).

Comment: It turns out it's not assigning any value to THISVARIABLE. It's empty. There's something else wrong here, on my end of it. I'm trying to figure out what. :)

Comment: @PaoloVacirca Perhaps check if `mypythonvariable` is empty? (That's what the sample code is assigning to...)

Comment: It is empty. I don't understand why though. I must have missed something in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turns out the error was in my configuration file. The "if" was never the case, because "varname" was never "THISVARIABLE". Why was it never so? Because I just didn't think about the fact that every line in the configuration file.txt started with a tab. So when I printed the lines, it all looked ok (I thought) yet "mypythonvariable = value" was never invoked. That also explained why it complained about the variable not being defined, I guess. Because the variable was never assigned a value. I solved it with lstrip(). Stupid mistake, but I always learn.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because a line in your thefile.txt file:

TEST = ABC

will be evaluated in python as TEST will be assigned to a value of variable ABC but you have no ABC defined.

You could make a dictionary to store your value pairs... this will work with string values:

```
variables = {}
accepted = ['THISVARIABLE', 'ANOTHERONE']
...
if varname in accepted:
    variables[varname]=value
```

Answer (score 0):

**eval** throws the error, the `value_string`'s value (which should be a variable) needs to be defined before use.